# Dividing time to get a percentage

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, percentage, excel-2013

Here's my setup:  I'm making a log for a time event I'm doing (think of it like sprinting), with a cumulative time broken up into segmented times, formatted as `[hh:mm:ss.000]` time values.

What I want to do is figure out how much time of a segment is of the cumulative time in the form of a percentage.

What I'm looking to do is basically do `A6(segment)/A10(cumulative time)*100`, however that formula obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If stop watch times (start at `0` in A1) then try in B2 copied down to suit and formatted as Percentage:

```
=(A2-A1)/A$10
```